# What is the purpose of cloning JUri in the CMSApplication route method?

Tags: jroute

CMSApplicationWhen Joomla does its initial routing in `Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication` in the `route` method, the JUri object is cloned. The line is:

```
$uri = clone \JUri::getInstance();
```

Looking at the code for `\JUri::getInstance()`, when called without a parameter, it will contain the URI based on the `SERVER` variables.

Why is this cloned, rather than just assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Object cloning is done so that subsequent actions on the object are applied purely to the "detached replica" (cloned object) and not the original object.

By not cloning, in other words just declaring the preexisting object as a new variable, you enjoy (or not) the effects of using a reference variable.  In all usages and for the life of the two variables, all actions on either variable -- will be "shared" and will affect both objects.

There is more to this story regarding "shallows copies" and "deep copies", but I'm probably not well positioned to speak on this.  If there are fringe cases that defy the *truths* that I have stated above, then I am unaware of them.

I've extended [this Stack Overflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2144654/2943403) to show the marriage between non-cloned objects, and the independence of cloned objects.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/rN6kU)

I have an example where cloning is beneficial during the process of building a mysql query with separate Joomla database objects. Scroll to the bottom of my answer at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24148/12352

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the differences between cloning an assignment of objects, my question was specifically about theJUri object and why its cloned rather than just assigned

Comment: I am not at my computer right now, nor have I looked up the line of code in the core,  but I'll venture that a second and untethered copy of the object was required for a subsequence process.  I'll have a closer look when I can -- but that might be this weekend.