# Delete query and left join with JDatabaseQuery doesn't work

Tags: mysql, jdatabase, joomla-4

I'm trying to convert a delete query with left join to use JDatabaseQuery, but I am encountering an issue in the query. The query that I'm trying to convert and which works is the following :

```
$db->setQuery("DELETE u FROM #__mycomponent_users AS u
               LEFT JOIN #__users AS ju ON u.userid=ju.id
               WHERE ju.username IS NULL");
```

I have converted it to JDatabaseQuery, with the following code:

```
$db->getQuery(true)
   ->delete($db->quoteName('#__mycomponent_users', 'u'))
   ->leftJoin($db->quoteName('#__users', 'ju') . ' ON u.userid=ju.id')
   ->where('ju.username IS NULL');
$db->setQuery($query);
```

In this, it returns the following error :

> Syntax error near 'AS `u` LEFT JOIN `jt5il_users` AS `ju` ON u.userid=ju.id WHERE ju.username IS NUL'

So how can I make this query work by using JDatabaseQuery?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you want to delete rows from one or more tables in a DELETE query containing a JOIN, you will need to specify the table(s) to delete between DELETE and FROM.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/2763206/2943403

Joomla's `delete()` method does not provide the necessary output - as you have discovered.

If you wish to patch the output from the query methods, then you can replace your:

```
$db->setQuery($query);
```

with:

```
$db->setQuery(preg_replace('~DELETE \K~', 'u ', $query, 1));
```

The `\K` metacharacter in the pattern says "forget/release any previously matched characters".  By using this technique, no characters are removed -- only `u` then a space are added.

Or because you only have one `DELETE` in your query, you can more simply adjust the sql string with:

```
$db->setQuery(str_replace('DELETE', 'DELETE u', $query));
```

This issue seems like reasonable grounds for an adjustment in core Joomla's `delete()` method so that a hack isn't required.  However, maybe this is too uncommon of a fringe case to bother with.

If the string replacement hack is too dirty for your taste, there are a few ways to perform this kind of mysql operation.  You might prefer to build a subquery to delete against.  ([An example of Joomla subquery implementation.](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24148/12352))

See these other sql options:

- https://networking.ringofsaturn.com/SQL/SQLDeleteRowsNotInAnotherTable.php
- [Delete sql rows where IDs do not have a match from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3384143/2943403)

Comment: I have tried this code snippet : `$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->delete($db->quoteName('#__mycomponent_users'))
            ->leftJoin($db->quoteName('#__users', 'ju') . ' ON userid = ju.id')
            ->where('ju.username IS NULL');
$db->setQuery($query);
` I still obtain the error : syntax error near 'LEFT JOIN `jt5il_users` AS `ju` ON userid = ju.id WHERE ju.username IS NULL'

Comment: The dump give : ```DELETE 
FROM `jt5il_mycomponent_users`
LEFT JOIN `jt5il_users` AS `ju` ON userid = ju.id
WHERE ju.username IS NULL```

Comment: In Phpmyadmin it throws the same error, for you second code snippnet there are the same error, the dump give : ```DELETE 
FROM `jt5il_mycomponent_users`
LEFT JOIN `jt5il_users` AS `ju` ON `jt5il_mycomponent_users`.`userid` = ju.id
WHERE ju.username IS NULL``` Same issue in phpmyadmin

Comment: Literally the table is nammed ```#__mycomponent_users```

Comment: I have done a screenshot of phpmyadmin : https://imgur.com/6A7P8zI

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer for you.  Unfortunately, Joomla's query methods don't provide what you need out of the box.

Comment: @user3533235 have I resolved your issue or is there something that remains unsolved/unclear for you?

Comment: I don't have resolved this issue, for this kind of queries i just don't use JDatabaseQuery

Comment: If you are going to use the first snippet in your question, then there is no question to answer.   You are welcome to simply use `setQuery()` -- it is a clean, direct technique.  I recall testing my advice to be an accurate technique as well.  So how shall this page be resolved in the system? Did I waste my time providing support? With no upvotes on my answer, you may delete your question, but I think this page has value to researchers.  I don't know any other way to answer the question that I _think_ you are asking.

Comment: The last line of your question says: **So how can I make this query work by using JDatabaseQuery?**  I interpret that to mean "using Joomla's query building methods". My answer does that very thing.